# How to initialize mailbox in dialog using displaydialogAsync

Tags: office-js

In my Office Add-in for Outlook, I am launching a new dialog window in my react app using [Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#using-the-office-dialog-api-with-single-page-applications-and-client-side-routing).  This launches the new window and a new instance of my app as expected.  In this new instance, `Office.context` appears to be initialized; however, `Office.context.mailbox` is undefined.  Is there any way to load this new window with an instance of `Office.context.mailbox`?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?